# DevExpress WInForms - Add NewRow Button at ViewCaption

Tags: winforms, gridview, devexpress, master-detail

I am creating a WinForm which displays three levels of data.
Top Level: issue
2nd level: invoice
3rd level: invoice items

The issues are set, but each issue can have multiple invoices and each invoice multiple items on it.

Since I'm using embedded mode for the grid the data navigator is not available and newrows clutter the screen real estate too much.

I now want to add a "+" button next to the details ViewCaption, see image:

[image]

I can access the Text of the caption via view.ViewCaption but I can not find a way to add a button there.
Attempts to programmatically add empty details to catch the click event on the tab have also failed.

This seems like a know where to look problem, so i hope someone will point me there or tell me its futile, then I'll add a button somewhere in the grids.

Comment: For questions about DevExpress, it's faster to use the support features on the [DevExpress site](https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/ticket/list).

Comment: Yeah, I'm doing that in parallel. Thanks for having a look.

Comment: I think your top level object Issue needs to have 2 IList<> collection properties, one IList<Invoice> Invoices and an IList<InvoiceDetail> InvoiceItems. That way the Details Tab will display both child tabs. For each collection property on the main bound object, it will display a Detail Tab for those items.

Comment: I just made it a right click menu.
I was able to add dummy pages, but then could not catch the click event.
So i would have had to make dummy details to be able to catch a different event and switch focus back to the first tabview. *Shrug* Maybe I'll come back to this when I have the time, because I like the potential look.